# Is an orthogonal projector bounded in $L_p$-spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $P$ be an orthogonal projector on $C^\infty([0,1])$.

For $0<p<\infty$, we define for $f \in C^\infty$ the norm (quasi-norm if $p<1$) $\lVert f \rVert_p$ in the usual way. Moreover, we define
$$\lVert P\rVert_p := \sup \{\lVert Pf\lVert_p \ | \ \lVert f \rVert_p \leq 1 \}.$$

**Question:** Do we have, for every $0<p<\infty$, $\lVert P \rVert_p <\infty$? Actually, is it even true that $Pf$ is in $L_p$ if $f$ is in $L_p$?

Comment: What do you mean by "**In particular**, $P$ is a projector from $C^\infty$ to itself"? This does **not** follow from your assumptions, take e.g. $P$ to be the projection onto the space spanned by $f$ for any $f \in L^2 \setminus C^\infty$. Or is this an additional **assumption**?

Comment: Effectively, it was uncorrect as stated. I updated accordingly. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: So, **orthogonality** of the projection means $\langle f, f - Pf \rangle_{L^2} = 0$ for $f \in C^\infty$?

Comment: Exactly. Or equivalently, $\lVert P \rVert_2 =1$ with my notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:** $p<1$

Consider the function

\begin{equation*}
 f(t)
 =
 \begin{cases}
 L^{1/p}, & t<L^{-1} \\ 
 0,       &t \geq L^{-1}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
with $L_p$ quasinorm $1$.  Its Fourier coefficients are
\begin{equation*}
 c_N
 =
 \left< f, e^{2\pi i N \cdot}\right>
 =
 \frac{-i}{2\pi} \frac{L^{1/p}}{N} \left(1 - e^{-2\pi i N/L} \right).
\end{equation*}
Moreover, the $L_p$ quasinorm of the exponential is 
\begin{equation*}
 \|c_Ne^{2\pi i N \cdot}\|_{L_p}
 =
 \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{L^{1/p}}{N} 
 | \sin(\pi N /L) |
\end{equation*}

Let $P$ be the projector mapping  $e^{-2\pi i N_0\cdot}$ to $0$, for some fixed $N_0$.  If we let $L\rightarrow \infty$, we can see that the projector is not bounded on $L_p$ for $p<1$. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
\|Pf\|_{L_p([0,1])} 
&= \|f-c_{N_0}e^{2\pi i N_0 \cdot}\|_{L_p([0,1])} \\
&\geq \|c_{N_0}e^{2\pi i N_0 \cdot}\|_{L_p([1/2,1])} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{L^{1/p}}{N} 
 | \sin(\pi N /L) |\\
& \rightarrow \infty.
\end{align*}

**Remark:**

Of course $f$ is not smooth, but we can obtain the same result with a smooth approximation to $f$.

**Case 2:** $p=1,\infty$

Some $L_2$ projectors are bounded. For example, Shadrin proved the conjecture of de Boor that spline projectors are bounded on $L_\infty$ (cf. Shadrin, Acta Mathematica, 2001). Also, every idempotent measure corresponds to a bounded projector for $p=1,\infty$.

However, there are also unbounded projectors. For simplicity, consider the domain to be the circle $\mathbb{T}$. The idempotent measures have Fourier transforms that take the values 0 or 1.  Helson (cf. Helson, Proc. AMS, 1953) has shown that if the location of the zeros satisfy the following property P1, then the tempered distribution is not a finite measure, and hence the projector is unbounded:

P1: the sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be made periodic by adding or dropping a finite number of elements.

Rudin generalized this result to $\mathbb{T}^d$, showing that an idempotent measure $\mu$ should have a Fourier transform $\widehat{\mu}$ supported on the coset ring of $\mathbb{Z}^d$, (cf. Rudin, Pacific J. Math., 1959).

Comment: This proves that the result is false for $p<1$ (thank you!). What about $p\geq 1$?

Comment: I'm probably being dense, but having read Helson's paper I still don't see how you reach the conclusion about unbounded projector. I understand one can let $P$ be the multiplication on the Fourier side by an essentially nonperiodic $0-1$ sequence. By Helson's results, $P$ can't be a convolution with a finite measure. But why can we say that this sequence is a Fourier transform of a (non-finite) measure? Frankly, I don't even know what non-finite complex measures are.

Comment: Given the structure, a non-finite measure would be a tempered distribution. I changed the wording, so hopefully it is more clear. Possibly the missing point is the following. The bounded, linear, shift-invariant transformations on L_1 can be characterized as convolutions with finite Borel measures. So if P is a convolution with a tempered distribution that isn't a finite Borel measure, then it can't be bounded